# R find a folder under parent dir using loop

Tags: r, loops, directory

I have a parent folder and two level sub-directory, and I am trying to find the 3rd level folder under which level 2 folder, the structure is like this

Parent folder --> level 1

Manager folder: Tom / Jerry / Nancy etc --> level 2

Company folder: company A / company B / Company C etc --> level 3

e.g. parent folder/ Tom / company A

so I would like to find out company A is under which manager's folder, because company A is not always under Tom, so the dir path keeps changing every month. Currently, I am thinking the following code, but would like to if there is a more elegant way to do. Thank you!

```
mgr = c("Tom", "Nancy", "Jerry")
for i in length(mgr) { 
if(dir.exist(paste0("parent folder/", mgr[i],"/company A")) {the rest code}
else{i = i+1
if(dir.exist(paste0("parent folder/", mgr[i],"/company A") {the rest code}
else{i=i+1
if(dir.exist(paste0("parent folder/", mgr[i],"/company A") {the rest code}}}
```

Comment: What is your working directory (i.e. `getwd()`) and is that always the same?

Comment: the parent folder (level 1) is always the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#create a vector with all subfolders from "parent folder/" 
dirs <- list.dirs(path = "parent folder/", full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE)
#show the subdirectories that contain "company A"  in it's path
dirs[ grepl( "company A", dirs )]
```